# Building gcc-4.8

Tags: build, gcc4.8

I'm trying to compile gcc/g++ 4.8 on a 64-bit Fedora 17 server. I'm configuring the build process wit

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/gcc-4.8 --with-cpu=x86-64 --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multiarch
```

I then run make. The build chunks along for a while and then fails when it can't find crti.o. I noticed that the compile steps prior to the failure use -m32 option which means the compile is being performed for a 32-bit architecture.  When I searched for crti.o, I found it in the /usr/lib64 path, not the /usr/lib path, which typically is for 32-bits. I only want to compile for 64-bit, which is why I included the with-cpu argument to configure. Obviously, this isn't enough.

What arguments do I need to include in configure so that only 64-bit compiles are made of the source and only 64-bit system libraries and similar files are linked?

Answer (score 0):

I am also using 64-bit fc17 and have crti.o:

```
$ locate crti.o
/usr/lib/crti.o
/usr/lib64/crti.o
$ rpm -qf /usr/lib/crti.o
glibc-devel-2.15-58.fc17.i686
$ rpm -qf  /usr/lib64/crti.o
glibc-devel-2.15-58.fc17.x86_64
```

Try to explicitly install the 32-bit version of glibc-devel:

```
yum install glibc-devel.i686
```